# Reduce noise/improve shapes from an Image

Tags: shapes, noise, image-segmentation, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

With imagesegmentation I segmented objects from a webcam. But because of the bad light I get a lot of noise in the picture. I want now to improve the shape of the found objects. The only method i found is image opening and closing but the result is no as good as I wished. Does anyone know some other methods?

In [this folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6vxonjjrcfel6dw/5YkPNs3weV) I have the orginal image after the segmentation, the image after closing, and a picture of what kind of picture I'm looing for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try the opening-closing combination operator. This provides a better smoothing of the shapes. Further more varying the radii of opening and closing (called the [ASF](http://books.google.com/books?id=-ch3fZTh08EC&lpg=PA32&dq=alternating%20sequential%20filter&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false) - alternating sequential filtering) produces smoother results. 
There are a few demos online that use [fourier desciptors](https://code.google.com/p/ij-shape-smoothing/). Its also important to choose a good shape of structuring elements, since your closing seems to close convex holes in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If it is salt/pepper noise, a simple median filter may be better.